# pass json from one node server to another - most efficient way?

Tags: json, node.js

I am an intermediate level in node.
I need to pass JSON  from one node.js server to another node.js (both servers are independant of each other and meant for different functions). The JSON data can be between 200 bytes to 50 KiloBytes. (upto 500 requests for second)

I was using http post but it stopped working over node.js 0.12.7. I cannot downgrade node and run the risk of breaking some other functionality. So I am looking for an alternative method to pass JSON data between the two Servers.

Here is my code for the POST request:

```
  function contactPushServerToSendMessage(recipients, entireMessage) {

   var post_options = {
       host: '<devServer>.cloudapp.net',
       port: '80',
      path: '/api/'+'sendMessage',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': entireMessage.length
    }
  };

 console.log("with body: " + entireMessage);

 // Set up the request
 var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
                                          res.setEncoding('utf8');
                                          res.on('data', function   (chunk) {
                                                                   console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
                                                  });
                         });

    // post the data
    post_req.write(entireMessage);
    post_req.end();

   }
 }
```

And here is the error message this returns:

```
Error: "name" and "value" are required for setHeader().
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:333:11)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:101:14)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at contactPushServerToSendMessage (/home/azureuser/myAppServer/nodeServer.js:297:23)
    at /home/azureuser/myAppServer/nodeServer.js:65:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/azureuser/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/azureuser/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/azureuser/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/azureuser/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/azureuser/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
```

Please advice what will be an efficient and reliable method to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example that shows how http post fails?

Comment: Sure, Dan. I'm trying to add it in comments but I will need to split it and the formatting is all messed up.

Do you know a better way to add to the original question?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32517345/edit) your question and include it there.

Comment: Thanks Dan. For some reason I could not find the link to edit my question.

I modified my code quite a bit and ended up overwriting parts of my POST request so am not able to test that piece and retrieve the error. I will work on setting up a separate file to get the code snippet and the error.

Comment: Dan, I have added the code and the error message it returns.

Please review and share your thoughts on this. HTTP(S) POST request out from node.js is still an important functionality that I see myself using in other areas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to find another example that worked for me - instead of using "http" module, I now am using "request" and this allowed me to successfully make HTTP POST requests.

Thank you for asking about the code, it made me revisit it after a break and was now able to see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this blog post:

http://www.sebastianseilund.com/json-socket-sending-json-over-tcp-in-node.js-using-sockets

It details how to pass JSON data by TCP using sockets.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, I will try it and report back.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I haven't implemented it yet, but going through the examples, this is what I wanted. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can always use some queue solutions, for example the AWS SQS, Kinesis etc.

As you have mentioned you could also use the POST request for that, but you get no guarantee for request reaching the destination. If you do want to use this pattern make sure you include some retry logic, the ACK response if the other server have received the message etc. That's why it is quicker to use some service for that.

SQS, queue based solution you need producer and consumer  - https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

Kinesis, allows realtime stream consuming - https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/

Comment: Thanks Risto.

I considered that, but for now I'm trying not to go that route as that adds another component in the mix.

Comment: I should add, the task I am handing over is not CPU intensive. The receiving server quickly needs to send pull information out and push it via APNS. the recipient server holds a connection to APNS server.